# Como crear un elemento html incrementando su id

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un pequeño programa que me cree unos divs y cuando me cree un nuevo div se me incremente un contador, para hacer tener un id unico en cada uno, el problema es que solo se me incrementa una sola vez luego y los nuevos que creo se me quedan con el mismo id.

Esté es mi JavaScript:

```js
function duplicate(){
    var i = 0;
    i++
    let campos = document.createElement('div');
    campos.id = 'id' + i ;
    document.getElementById('duplicados').appendChild(campos);
}
```

Por si sirve de algo este es mi html:

Este es el boton con el que activo la función

```
<center><input type="button" id="add" onclick="duplicate()" value="Añadir"></center>
```

Y los nuevos div los inserto en un div llamado "duplicados"

Comment: Tienes que declarar la variable `i` fuera de la función

Comment: La variable i tiene ámbito local, y se inicializa con 0 cada vez que invocas a la función, acto seguido la incrementas, por lo que en cada llamada, su valor termina siendo 1. campos.id termina siendo "id1" todas las veces. Usa una clase con una variable miembro estática o declara e inicializa por aparte de la función i, y solo la incrementas en la definción

Comment: Si quieres usa una variable global o sea, como propiedad de windos, por ejemplo windows.dups y ahí guardas el último id. O en la función cuentas el número de divs dentro de duplicados (si duplicados solo contiene los divs que añades con el script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juan Manuel, una forma de resolverlo tal y como lo tienes tú sería utilizando clases (siempre vienen bien para esto y otras cosas como estilos, etc.).
Te propongo algo así:

```
function duplicate(){
    let i=document.getElementsByClassName('elemento-repetido').length || 0,
        destino = document.getElementById('duplicados'),
        nuevo = document.createElement('div');
    i++;
    nuevo.id = 'id' + i ;
    nuevo.classList.add('elemento-repetido');

    destino.appendChild(nuevo);
}
```